# C# (RawInput, RegisterRawInputDevices)

Tags: c#, winapi, raw-input, user32

A function "RegisterRawInputDevices(RawInputDeviceRegistration[] pRawInputDevices, uint uiNumDevices, uint cbSize)" from user32.dll blocks the main GUI thread.
Is there a way to keep GUI active?

Repo is here: https://github.com/itdimk/NativeWindowPlay

There's a function "RegisterDevices" inside class "MacroRecorder".
Internally, it calls RegisterRawInputDevices from user32.dll.
Problem is, after that call GUI got completely blocked.

I tried to call it in a new thread but it doesnt help :c

Comment: Is it actually locking the UI thread? Or is it interrupting the thread to fire off an event every time that you try to click on the UI or use the keyboard? `RawInputReceiverWindow.WndProc` seems to called each time any input is made.

Comment: Window looks 100% unresponsive. Button doesn't change state on hover although mouse & keyboard is idle

Comment: It looks unresponsive but if you watch your debug output it's doing exactly what you told it to do. Every mouse movement, every key down and then key up event. it's all getting output to the console. When you click on the window that fires an event, if you try to click and drag to move the window that's firing off events. The UI thread never gets a chance to respond because it's constantly processing the event as the user tries to interact.